# Append JSON data to last line of adjacent div (without Grid and Flexbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table, append

I have four `divs` and I want to make it so that each JSON element is appended to the *next* div to the right of it rather than immediately below the previous element.

Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkg7z.png) that better explains what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm considering using a table and rows to create the desired effect, but if there's an easier way I can to do it then please let me know. Any thoughts on this one?

When I browsed SO and Google for info I could only find posts about appending data to divs...which is partially correct but not exactly what I'm going for. If there's already a SO post about what I'm trying to do, then feel free to send the link my way.

```js
var testjson = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "Title": "Training 1",
      "Category": "Enter Choice #1",
      "Topic": "Enter Choice #1",
      "Description": "My Test description",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 1,
      "Modified": "2019-03-05T20:13:46Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-05T20:13:36Z"
    }, {
      "Title": "Donec id dictum sem",
      "Category": "Enter Choice #1",
      "Topic": "Enter Choice #1",
      "Description": "Donec id dictum sem",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 10,
      "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:25Z"
    },
      "Title": "Mauris sagittis ligula",
      "Category": "Enter Choice #2",
      "Topic": "Enter Choice #2",
      "Description": "Mauris sagittis ligula",
      "TopTrainingCourse": true,
      "ID": 11,
      "Modified": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z",
      "Created": "2019-03-06T21:08:35Z"
    }]
  }
}

function loadTopCourses() {
  let isTop = testjson.d.results
    .filter(x => x.TopTrainingCourse === true)
    .map(x => {
      return {
        "Category": x.Category,
        "Title": x.Title
      }
    })

  let showTopCats = isTop;
  for (var i = 0; i < showTopCats.length; i++) {
    $(".top-training-tb").append("<tr>" + showTopCats[i].Category + "</tr>")
  };

} // ------------------ loadTopCourses

loadTopCourses();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-training">
  <h2>Top Training Courses</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="top-training-tb"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the structure of testjson so that we can have a fully replicable example?

Comment: Hi @basic I added a JSON snippet into my post.

Comment: You should not use tables for this layout. Check this out: https://mozilladevelopers.github.io/playground/css-grid

Comment: Unfortunately the main browser that this will be viewed in is IE11 which only has partial Grid support :(

Comment: If you use display flex instead of table tags I think you will get what you want.

Comment: @satwik I would, but flexbox doesn't have IE11 support.

Comment: Max how many columns u need in a row

Comment: @satwik 4 columns.